# Why can't I bind visible of a control without runat=server?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In other words, why can't I do this:

```
<a id="projectsButton" 
visible=<%= someFunctionWhichEvalsToFalse() ? false : true %>>
</a>
```

It seems to do nothing.  I checked this by switching the false and true.

What can I do about this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it, but it won't do anything, since HTML has no `visible` attribute.

Instead, you can set the `display` CSS property, like this:

```
<a id="projectsButton" 
   style="display: <%= someFunctionWhichEvalsToFalse() ? "none" : "inline" %>">
```

Alternatively, you can put the entire tag into an `if` block, like this:

```
<% if (!someFunctionWhichEvalsToFalse()) { %>
    <a id="projectsButton"></a>
<% } %>
```

Comment: If this is the case, why does Visual Studio give it as an attribute in IntelliSense?

Comment: The VS IntelliSense nonsense notwithstanding, this is the correct answer. +1 and accepted.

Comment: It's probably showing `Visible` because it's a legal attribute for HTML elements that are made into server conrols with `runat="server"`.

Answer (score 3):

Visible is only available to server controls, hence why you need runat="server"

If you want to do this without making that a server control, you could try something like:

```
<a id="projectsButton" style='display:<%= someFunctionWhichEvalsToFalse() ? "none" : "inline" %>'></a>
```

Comment: `<a>` tags are `inline`, not `block`.

Answer (score 2):

Put another way, your question is why can't you use a server control property on an HTML element without it being a server control.  The answer is because its not a server control, and server control properties only work on server controls.  HTML tags are treated as plain text.

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `display:none` in CSS to hide the element, although the element will be sent to the client. To really hide it you can wrap it in a `<asp:PlaceHolder>` control and bind the `Visible` attribute on the PlaceHolder.

```
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="placeholder" runat="server" Visible="<%# someFunctionWhichEvalsToFalse() %>">
    <a id="projectsButton" href="#">link</a>
</asp:PlaceHolder>
```

That will prevent the link html from being sent to the client.

Comment: You cant use <%= blah %> in an attribute of a server control. You must use <%# %> and databind instead, or set it from the code behind.

Answer (score 0):

This would render an `a` element to the screen with the `visible` attribute, which is not a valid attribute for an `a` element according to [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/links.html#h-12.2). You probably want to set the uppercase `Visible` property of the `HtmlGenericControl` that will be created in your designer file as a result of adding `runat="server"` to the declaration of the element.